# Search a hard drive for large files

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I have a computer with the main C: drive getting full. I want to figure out what's on it and where. Searching for large files doesn't do me any good though.

Issues:

- There are multiple user accounts. I need to search inside these user folders.
- I want to know about swap files, paging files, hibernation files,
  etc.
- I want to know about large sub directories in the Windows folder. Not
  all are instantly accessible and I don't know what ones a standard
  search is excluding.
- I don't have a good way of knowing how large the system recovery
  section is.

As it stands now I can highlight the folders on my C: and hit "Properties" and see that they contain 63GB of files. I'm missing another 120GB though! I want to know what it is and where it is. I am an Administrator.

Comment: Have you tried WinDirStats? http://windirstat.info/index.html

Comment: I have not - really don't know any applications that can do this. Will take a look at it.

Comment: Not bad. As I mentioned above, Windows shows 63 GB in use from the "Properties" on the folders on the drive. But the main drive overview window shows 176.8 GB in use. This application was able to identify 170.1 GB. So it is not finding everything but it certainly found a lot.

Comment: This could simply be a difference in reporting or cluster size... WinDirStat is good, there are several other tools though. http://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/

Comment: You can't just right click Properties on your system drive, many reasons for that, but basically Windows keeps a single copy of a file but has several links to that folder.  When you determine your usage through Properties each link is counted.  If WinDirStat only lists what files the user which runs it has access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info) is a great free tool that can visualise how much space files and folders take up on your computer. There is also a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/windirstat_portable) if you want to run it from a USB stick or don't want to install anything on the computer.

[image]

To access locations where UAC would be invoked, try holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right-clicking on the WinDirStat icon and then clicking on `Run as administrator`.

Comment: I prefer TreeSizeFree, much better overview compared to this UI mess

Comment: You can hide the multi-coloured blocks at the bottom of the UI if you want. They are quite a nice way to quickly spot large files and large file types, but it's not essential to have visible.

Comment: for me this is the most confusing part. you can't see anything useful from it. They are just wasting space that you would need for the TreeView